# How to know if a transactional method in a grails service was successful?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-services

I have something like this:

```
class SomeService {
   static transactional = true

    def someMethod(){
      ...
      a.save()
      ....
      b.save()
      ....
      c.save()
      ....
      etc...
}
```

}

I want to know if the transactional method was successful or not, I don't want to check the error property in each domain object because the logic involve many domain classes and it would be difficult.

Comment: What I mean with "transactional method was successful " is if the transaction is successful, in other words if a roll back was executed or not.

Comment: Check the example in the end of the answer for the same. :)

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
a.save(failOnError: true) 
b.save(failOnError: true)
c.save(failOnError: true) 
d.save(failOnError: true)
```

I'm assuming what you want is the service to throw exception on error of a single domain save, and rollback the transaction in such cases.

Comment: This work, thank you I just have to check if the method throws and exception or not and I know if the transaction was executed successfully or not.   (btw, I just wanna know if the transaction was successful just to tell the user what is happening (send an error message))

Answer (score 3):

There are number of ways you can check the same:-

1. As you do not want to trace all the `saves` in the service class, I guess you would also not like tracing each of the save to set `failOnError` flag too. Alternative approach is to set `grails.gorm.failOnError=true` in `Config.groovy` which automatically checks for each save and throws a `ValidationException` in case validation on domain class fails. `ValidationException` is a `RuntimeException` therefore transaction will be rolled back if one thrown. Have a look at [failOnError](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) to get the idea.
2. (Little less verbose in your case) Save method returns the domain object itself in case of a success otherwise null if validation fails. Again you have trace all the `saves` to check something like `if(a.save()){...}`, `if(b.save()){...}`, blah, blah....
3. (I think the appropriate approach) Will be to use `TransactionAspectSupport` to get the transaction status and check if it is set to rollback only. If it is not then you are good.

For example:

```
def someMethod(){
   try{
      ...
      a.save()
      ....
      b.save()
      ....
      c.save()
      ....
      etc...
   }catch(e){
      //It can also be used as a last line in method instead of checking
      //in catch block.
      println TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isRollbackOnly() 
   }

   //println TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isRollbackOnly() 

}
```

Comment: I was looking exactly for something like this, but I will use the @JavaDev solution because in that way I can know the error that caused the roll back.

Comment: @LxZv That solution is also mentioned as point #1 in an optimized way.