# Grails manual transactions and rollback

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

```
class A {
    ...
    static hasMany = [bees: B]
}

class B {
    static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

Now, we create about 10,000 instances of B (from a service) that belongs to an A at a time, but if 1 fails it should roll back all the successfully created ones. I have tried a few methods, none worked:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < batch.numToMake; i++) {
        def b = new B().save(flush: i % 1000 == 0)

        if (i == 50) {
            throw new RuntimeException("simulate")
        }
    }

    batch.status = Constants.BATCH_STATUS_DONE
    batch.save(flush: true)
} catch (e) {
    // This was a last resort test and still did not work
    batch.status = Constants.BATCH_STATUS_FAILED
    batch.vouchers.each {
        batch.removeFromVouchers(it)
    }

    batch.save(flush: true)
}
```

---

```
// This did not work at all
B.withTransaction { status ->
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < batch.numToMake; i++) {
            def b = new B().save(flush: i % 1000 == 0)

            if (i == 50) {
                throw new RuntimeException("simulate")
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        status.setRollbackOnly()
    }
}
```

---

Can anyone help out how I can create large volumes of a item in the hasMany / belongsTo relationship, but roll back everything on fail of 1, from a service class.

---

Comment: Point 3 from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17357547/2051952) is what I suppose is the best option for you in this case, assuming you are using grails services.

Answer (score 0):

Your service needs to be transactional (put grails @Transactional annotation on top of the service class), then you don't need to try/catch. Any RuntimeException thrown from the method will trigger a transaction rollback.
So you can simply do the following:

```
def import() {
    def a = A.get(1L)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        new B(a: a).save()

        // runtime exception thrown here would rollback everything
    }
}
```

What you need to take care of when working with batches is to make sure that the session does not grow too large. You can prevent that by getting a handle to the current session and then flush and clear it:

```
def import() {
    Parent.withSession { session ->
        def a = A.get(1L)
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            new B(a: a).save()

            // runtime exception thrown here would rollback everything

            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                session.flush()
                session.clear()
            }

            // runtime exception thrown here would rollback everything
        }
    }
```