# Service call back to a Controller?

Tags: grails

Grails makes it very easy for a Controller to call into a Service and for a Controller to forward a request onto another Controller.

So suppose you have a service method as such

```
List<String>  updateNames() {
   ...
}
```

You can call it very easily from any controller.

I am wondering, say if you have an edge case where you realise there is a validation problem in your service method.  You don't want to throw an Exception back to your controller, because it is not really an exceptional case.  But you can't return back an error message from your Service to the Controller that called because that will mean you have to use some wrapper object instead of a nice List

Is there anyway for these cases, you can get the Service to do a server side forward onto another Controller which could return an Error response to user?

Thanks.

Comment: This would seem to me an ideal use case for an exception...

Comment: Agree with Sèrgio and Joshua. All validation exceptions can be handled before even going to service class by use of Command Objects or domain instance itself. As Joshua mentioned about separation of concern, service should not know about the http call or any validation issues. It should care about business exceptions/scenarios. Being said that, throwing a runtime exception or error from service will be the last thing I would do to rollback transaction. We should use [`TransactionAspectSupport`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17357547/2051952) to handle rollback.

Comment: @Ian Roberts Why? This is something you expect might happen, a user might enter the wrong data. Nothing has actually gone wrong in your system per se.

Answer (score 2):

Grails already have a structure for validation in your beans, called [Errors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html?is-external=true) (comming form Spring). For example, if you have a service to upload files, you could easily attach validation errors in your bean:

```
class UploadService {
  void doUpload(MultipartFile file, MyDomainClass domainClassInstance) {
    if(validationsFail) {
      domainClassInstance.errors.rejectValue("myUploadField","my.i18n.code")
    }
  }
}
```

If it's not a domain class, you can consider using a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) since they're validateable too.

In your controller, it's just a metter of checking if your instance has errors:

```
def upload() {
  MyDomainClass instance = ...
  uploadService.doUpload(request.getFile('file'), instance)
  if(!instance.hasErrors()) {
    //save and go on...
  }
}
```

Another option is to work with exceptions like @Joshua Moore answered. Just remember to extend `RuntimeException`. If you don't, your transaction will not be rolledback automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Services are not aware of the web/http request context in this way. I won't get into how this line is blurred with session or request scoped services since it still doesn't apply to what you are asking about. Plus, you really don't want your service to even be aware that it's dealing with a web/http request, since you want to separate responsibilities and have a good/clean design.

So, back to your question. This is exactly the case for raising an exception from your service and letting your controller handle the result of that exception. If it's a validation error on an instance then you should be able to access the errors collection of the instance in your controller (provided of course that it was an input into your service).

As a side note about exceptions from services. Stack traces are expensive to fill in. This is even more so in Grails since there are a lot of pieces at work. I highly recommend if you are going to raise your own business logic exceptions from your services that you override the fillInStackTrace method on your exception to avoid this cost.

Here is an example:

```
package com.example

class MyBusinessException extends RuntimeException {

    List<String> argList = []

    public MyBusinessException (String message, List<String> args){
        super(message)

        argList = args
    }

    public MyBusinessException (String message){
        super(message)
    }

    /**
    * Don't fill in the stack trace because we want things to be faster.
    **/
    @Override
    public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        // do nothing
        return this
    }
}
```